# How to call a function in V8() R Package with arguments

Tags: javascript, r, v8

I tried to "browserify" this package [Google-Play-Scraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-play-scraper) so I can use it in R. However, I cannot seem to know how I can call a function.

rCode.R:

```
ct <- v8()
ct$source("scraper/googleplayscraperbundle.js")
test_app <- "{\"appId\":\"com.mojang.minecraftpe\",\"page\":0}"
pretty_test <- ct$call("scraper.reviews", test_app)
```

Output

[image: Output of pretty_test]
This is the snippet of how to use the reviews function. [Review Function Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-play-scraper#reviews)

```
gplay.reviews({
  appId: 'com.mojang.minecraftpe',
  sort: gplay.sort.RATING
}).then(console.log, console.log);
```

Comment: How did you do the bundle ? I tried and it doesn't work when I call `ct$source`.

Comment: I think (really not sure) that `test_app` must be an R object. Could you try `test_app <- list(appId = "com.mojang.minecraftpe", page =0)`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I tried `test_app <- list(appId = "com.mojang.minecraftpe", page =0)` however I get the same result as the output above.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I just use this command in terminal `browserify googleplayscraper.js -o googleplayscraperbundle.js` to do the bundle and then remove all the code that uses `window` when I encountered `window is not defined` error

Comment: Ok. Does not work for me :( What about `ct$call("function(x){scraper.reviews(x).then(console.log,console.log)}", test_app)` ?